# What is the correct usage for I'm a girl in my early twenties?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, possessives, personal-pronouns

Which is grammatically correct?

> I am a girl in **my** early twenties.

or

> I am a girl in **her** early twenties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grammatically, both versions work; they would be parsed as

> (I am) (a girl (in her early twenties))

That is, you are a single thing: a girl of a particular age range.

vs.

> (I am) ((a girl) (in my early twenties))

That is, you are two things: a girl, and in a particular age range.

Semantically, the two things are equivalent; say whichever feels more natural to you.

Comment: Well, that's apart from the casual sexism ...